# Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue> Class tiempo de expiración - C#

Tags: c#, webservice

Alguien sabe si el Diccionario de DATOS en C# tiene un periodo de expiración.

Tengo un webservices en un SERVIDOR de Windows con IIS donde voy poblando el diccionario, cada que agrego instantaneamente los agrega bien pero despues de un rato como que se Inicializa por que cuando veo el historial de lo que contiene mi DICCIONARIO no contiene NADA (Tengo una pantalla independiente donde voy y consulto lo POBLADO)

```
public static Dictionary<String, List<Costumers>> DiccionarioCostumer = new Dictionary<String, List<Costumers>>();
        public static Dictionary<String, List<Unidad>> DiccionarioUnidad = new Dictionary<String, List<Unidad>>();
        public static Dictionary<String, List<Pais>> DiccionarioPais = new Dictionary<String, List<Pais>>();

        [WebMethod]
        public RespuestaCS validaDatos(
            ArrayListParent1 listaCostumers,
            ArrayListParent2 listaUnidad,
            ArrayListParent3 listaPais
            )
        {
            // CODIGO donde hago toda la operacion para insertar a los DICCIONARIOS 

            //CODE

            //EJEMPLO
            DiccionarioCostumer.Add(listaCostumers.getId(), listaCostumers.getName());
            DiccionarioUnidad.Add(listaUnidad.getId(), listaUnidad.getName());

        }
```

Comment: pues puedes programar un timer y colocar tu diccionario en openWith.Clear();

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo pero la función Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue> Class EXPIRA en algún momento.

Ejemplo: si yo pongo un TIME que me borre cada que haga 15 dias o un MES pero si la funcion Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue> Class solo dura horas, entonces lo que quiero saber es si tiene algun TIEMPO DE VIGENCIA ESA FUNCION, gracias.

Comment: Cuando creas una variable de tipo `Dictionary<string, string>` no es una función, es un objeto si hablamos en términos de POO y hasta donde conozco no tiene un tiempo de expiración, lo he usado en proyectos donde permanecen con datos almacenados durante días y nunca se han inicializado a no ser que mi propio código lo haga; te recomiendo que revises en detalles la pila de llamadas de tu proyecto, en algún punto de tu código alguna linea debe estar inicializando el  `Dictionary<string, string> openWith` por ejemplo si en algún punto estas llamando `openWith = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

Comment: sabias que una variable `static` se comporta como el objeto `Application`, o sea, los datos son globales al sitio web y puede causar problemas de concurrencia. Eviata usar static en desarollo de servicios, mejor usa el cache si necesitas algo global, o si es para el usuario el Session

Answer (score 1):

Parto de la base que un servicio web no tiene estado, sino que hay que configurarlo para poder hacer uso del objeto `Session`, el cual no veo que estes usando en el codigo que no muestras.

[WebService.Session Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webservice.session?view=netframework-4.5)

Como veras se usa el `EnableSession` en el `WebMethod` para poder usar el objeto `Session`

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="Util" %>
 
 using System.Web.Services;
 
 public class Util: WebService {
   [WebMethod(Description="Per session Hit Counter",EnableSession=true)]
    public int SessionHitCounter() {
       if (Session["HitCounter"] == null) {
          Session["HitCounter"] = 1;
       }
       else {
          Session["HitCounter"] = ((int) Session["HitCounter"]) + 1;
          }
       return ((int) Session["HitCounter"]);
    }   
 }
```

El `Dictionary<>` no tiene estado es solo una variable que se pierde despues de cada request.

Cuando creas el diccionario deberias asignarlo a la session para tener luego el dato en el proximo request.

```
Session["open"] = openWith;
```

Para recuperarlo usarias

```
var openWith = Session["open"] as Dictionary<string, string>;
```